# In Laravel, using Http Client, how can I get the headers that will be sent in the request?

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I'm making a request using the Laravel Http Client, and I want to know the exact headers that will be sent (or were sent) in the request. I'm not trying to set them. I want to read them.

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Comment: It's a wrapper around Guzzle and the defaults for that are configured [here](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/7.8/src/Client.php#L229). As far as I can tell it's only the user agent that is added by default

Answer (score 0):

You should enable debug output, like so :

```
$client->request('POST', $url, ['form_params' => [$value], 'debug' => true]);
```

check document

https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#debug